# Rails 4: Post and Comment in ajax on Index action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I try to make a simple Post / Comment function in my index action, but I also try to do it in ajax (for the moment, on the Comment, but I get this error:
         ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `comment'

Here's my files :

comments_controller.rb

```
    def create
      @posts = Post.includes(:comments).order("created_at DESC")
      @comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)
       respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.save
       format.js {render 'posts/create'}
        else
       redirect_to :back
        end
      end
     end
```

index.html.erb

```
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.user.email %></td>
    <td><%= post.content %></td>

    <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div id="comment">
      <%= render :partial => 'comment_ajax', :locals => { :comment => comment } %>
    </div> 
    <% end %>

    <%= form_for @comment, remote: true do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_field :content %>
     <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
```

posts_controller.rb

```
 def index
   @posts = Post.includes(:comments).order("created_at DESC")
   @comment = Comment.new
   @post = Post.new
 end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :posts
resources :comments
```

create.js.erb

```
 $("#comment").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'posts/comment_ajax', :locals => { :comment => comment }) %>");
```

_comment_ajax.html.erb

```
 <%= comment.content %>
```

I know it's because of my ":locals => { :comment => comment }" in my create.js.erb file, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `:locals => { :comment => @comment }` in `create.js.erb` for locals?

Comment: Ok... It's seems to be working! Thank you! But now I have a problem for display the new content, I think it's something wrong with my <div id="comment">. Thank you !

Comment: I am unable to understand the new issue.  The content of `#comment` div should be replaced by the created comment content.  Oh, is it that you want to `append()` instead of `html()`?

Comment: I've never seen appendHtml() used in this kind of case, shoul'd I ?

Comment: It should've been `append()` not `appendHtml()`, corrected in comment.  If you're trying to append the new comment to the `#comment` div then yes, use `append()`, if you want to replace the content of `#comment` div then use `html()`.

Comment: Yes, append() work (it add a new record every time), but, it always show the new record on the first "post" and when I reload the page, everything is in the right place. Thank you for you help!